# Smarty {fetch} in .tpl and Variables

Tags: smarty

I'm using smarty and inside of a .tpl file, I have

```
{fetch file='http://domain.com/directory/{$wtc_location}/{$wtc_year}/{$wtc_stormname}.php'}
```

but its not pulling the variables. I've tried `{$smarty.get.wtc_location}` and still nothing. What is the solution to get the variables to load?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: why do you mean by "its not pulling the variables"? if i.e. $wtc_location is empty, you must assign some value to it in the template or in the php file with $smarty->assign('wtc_location', 'some location');

Comment: All the variables is set, it just returns [link]http://domain.com/directory/{$wtc_location}/{$wtc_year}/{$wtc_stormname}.php[/link] but i can take that line outside of the fetch and it pulls all the variables in correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I see the problem. You cannot call a smarty variable inside a smarty function as if it was a template, you have to use the modifier [cat](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.modifier.cat.tpl) to compose it:

```
{fetch file='http://domain.com/directory/'|cat:$wtc_location|cat:'/'|cat:$wtc_year|cat:'/'|cat:$wtc_stormname|cat:'.php'}
```